# How to define global variables?

Tags: pdftex

How to define global variables?

How to define global variables? If "global variable" is term only used in programming, then what I want is a method to store something and change or use it when needed.

Below is my method

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\varx}{}
\newcommand{\setx}[1]{\renewcommand{\varx}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\setx{abc}
\varx
\setx{def}
\varx
\end{document}
```

There're problems:

1. I have to use a separate command for each variable to change their value.
2. It seems strange. As if there should've been another command to do this. (Just that I don't know it.)

By the way, I don't know what tag to use.

Comment: Technically, there are no global variables in TeX, only global values.  Inside a group any macro or register can be changed but the change will be local.  You can make global changes explicitly using `\global` (as in `\global\let` or `\global\advance`).  Note that counter commands always use global changes.

Answer (score 2):

TeX provides tokens registers. You can declare a new token register by `\newtoks\abc`, set the value to it by `\abc={value}` or `\abc{value}` and use the value by `\the\abc`. The problem is that `\newtoks` declares a control sequence without checking if it is already defined, so `\newtoks\end` is allowed but your LaTeX document (if you are using LaTeX, sic) is corrupted after this. I suggest to define a macro `\declvar` which runs `\newtoks` only if declared control sequence is undefined. The macro has following syntax

```
\declvar\sequence {default value}
```

The implementation and test follows:

```
\def\declvar #1{%
   \ifx#1\undefined 
       \newtoks#1#1%
   \else
      \errmessage{\string\declvar: \string#1 cannot be var, it is defined already}%
      \toks0
   \fi}

\declvar\abc {default value}

\the\abc  % expands to "default value"

\abc={new value}

\the\abc  % expands to "new value"

\declvar\begin {default} % throws error message
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use \def \variablename {variable}

For example

```
\def  \varx {2}
\varx

\def \varx {a+b=400}
\varx
```

Outputs this:  [image: Output]

Just be careful not using anything latex uses (for example, don't use \def \begin{3})

Comment: Don’t you just hate when you’re in the mood to define a command `\begin` which just prints `3` and then your day is just ruined like that?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what these “variables” should contain. A generic container is known in `expl3` as “token list”.

You can bypass the problem of already defined commands by using a sort of namespace.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setvar}{mm}
 {
  % clear an existing variable or allocate a new one
  \tl_clear_new:c { g__youthdoo_var_#1_tl }
  % set to the stated value
  \tl_gset:cn { g__youthdoo_var_#1_tl } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  % deliver the contents
  \tl_use:c { g__youthdoo_var_#1_tl }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setvar{x}{abc}

\usevar{x}

\setvar{x}{def}

\usevar{x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are more specific variable types, for instance floating point numbers.